# Create a string depending on the number of values in an array

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm trying to create a linear gradient in CSS with Javascript. Enter your values like so `SomeFunction("#009DFF", "#FFF", "EFEFEF")` and then I'm trying to create a string like

```
var css = "linear-gradient(to right, #009DFF, #EFEFEF, #FFF)"
```

I'm currently using this to count the number of items in the array, I just need help concatenating the values to the string. Any ideas?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var colorCount = arguments.length;
}
```

Comment: You have no idea how to make a string or how to concatenate? Also, I'm guessing the string you show here is a typo? You reversed the last two values.

Comment: I know how to do that, I just need to get **all** the values into one string. And a typo? @putvande

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the arguments to an array, join the values and return it with the extra CSS bits:

```
function SomeFunction() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + args.join(", ") + ')';
}

var css = SomeFunction("#009DFF", "#FFF", "EFEFEF");
```

would output:

```
linear-gradient(to right, #009DFF, #FFF, EFEFEF)
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0fgny5bm/)

Answer (score -1):

Either use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) or add strings with the + operator. If you have an array of strings you want to combine, consider using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead.